# Decimal parse issue when exporting to excel

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I am trying to export data to excel and currently using this code source: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/659666/Export-very-large-data-to-Excel-file

I get data from firebird database, and half of the fields are decimals. The problem is when I export data to Excel, all my decimal values like 123,45 will be **treated as text in Excel**, however values like 0 or 200 are treated as numbers.

I've tried parsing my values like this:

```
public static bool isDecimal(string s)
    {
    NumberStyles style;
    CultureInfo culture;
    decimal number;

    style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.Float;
    culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(s, style, culture, out number))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

But when I use the above function when I write to Excel, it doesn't work:

```
foreach (DataRow dsrow in ResultsData.Rows)
{
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Row();

    foreach (DataColumn col in ResultsData.Columns)
    {
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Cell();

        if (isDecimal(dsrow[col].ToString()))
        {
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number;
        }
        else
        {
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
        }
        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(dsrow[col].ToString());

        newRow.AppendChild(cell);
    }

    sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
}
```

P.S. My country uses Russian culture info (123,45) not (123.45)

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is the culture of the spreadsheet - it is recognizing the 123,45 as a number. Is there a way to change culture of `sheetData`?

If not, perhaps you could replace ',' with '.' for the import and format column appropriate for RU?
I would say it is the culture of the spreadsheet - it is recognizing the 123,45 as a number. Is there a way to change culture of `sheetData`?

If not, perhaps you could replace ',' with '.' for the import and format column appropriate for RU? e.g.

```
       string value; 
       if (isDecimal(dsrow[col].ToString()))
        {
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number;
            value = dsrow[col].ToString()
        }
        else
        {
            cell.DataType = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
            value = dsrow[col].ToString().Replace(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator, ".");
            // Or simply
            // value = dsrow[col].ToString().Replace(",", ".");
        }
        cell.CellValue = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.CellValue(value);
```

Comment: I do not think there is a way of changing the culture of sheetData. In Excel itself, it recognizes 123.45 as text, and 123,45 as number.